# How to retrieve all records in a string after a certain value

Tags: java, string, loops

I am looking to retrieve all of the values after "xnum=" and before the "," delimiter. For example, in the below String, i would like to retrieve the values "zjdb" and "2jdb" and store them in an array in the order they are found. I know this is a very random thing to ask for but it's unfortunately the only way to solve the problem i am currently faced with.

```
String: "{zjdb={fname=jbdjd, lname=ejdj, xnum=zjdb, email=ejdj}, 2jdb={fname=ij, lname=vji, xnum=2jdb, email=bbb}}"
```

I understand that i need to loop through and search for "x" and then see if the next character is "n" and the next is "u" etc and then get the index after the "=" and upto the "," but i've thought about this too much and it's too complex for me to get. I'm wondering if anyone knows a somewhat simple solution to this..? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Do you have any control over what this String looks like?  Because this is *very* close to being valid JSON, and there are tons of libraries out there that can parse JSON.

Comment: You're going to have to parse the string. And regular expressions won't work here because you're working with nested data. Unfortunately, the object format you posted is not any sort of standard object format I'm aware of (the closest thing is JSON). Either you will have to write your own parser, or find some sort of Java toString() parser online.

Comment: If you had access to the map object *before* it is transformed into that string, that would make this problem x100 easier. Or, if you have access to the transformation logic, use a JSON transformer and then parse the JSON string on your end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find the tokens. Assuming that the input is well formatted e.g. after `xnum=` value there is either `,` or `}`:

```
String input = "{zjdb={fname=jbdjd, lname=ejdj, xnum=zjdb, email=ejdj}, 2jdb={fname=ij, lname=vji, xnum=2jdb, email=bbb}}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[{ ]xnum=([^,}]+)[,}]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
  String xnum = m.group(1);
  System.out.println(xnum);
}
```

Comment: He doesn't just want to read the value of `xnum`. The `,` he is referring to is not the comma immediately succeeding the value of `xnum`, but the comma separating the `zjdb` and `2jdb` entries. Regular expressions won't work here.

Comment: @mario_sunny It's stated in the question: *to retrieve the values "zjdb" and "2jdb"* which can be done with above code. Parsing JSON with regex is wrong but at the moment OP didn't provide more context.

Comment: I would also include `}` as end of searched value, just in case...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex and some replace to clean your text.

For instance you can have something like this:

```
String str = "{zjdb={fname=jbdjd, lname=ejdj, xnum=zjdb, email=ejdj}, 2jdb={fname=ij, lname=vji, xnum=2jdb, email=bbb}}";
String[] result = str.replaceAll(".*?(xnum[^}]*).*", "$1")
                     .replaceAll(", *", ",")
                     .split(",");

for (String item : Arrays.asList(result)) {
    System.out.println(item.split("=")[1]);
}
```

**[IdeOne demo](https://ideone.com/Oh0PYn)**

Answer (score 0):

Below code gives output your are desiring. But @Karol Dowbecki 's approach is better. This code does same thing but without regular expression.

```
String input = "{zjdb={fname=jbdjd, lname=ejdj, xnum=zjdb, email=ejdj}, 2jdb={fname=ij, lname=vji, xnum=2jdb, email=bbb}}";

    String[] b = input.split(",");

    List<String> list = Arrays.stream(b).filter(s -> s.contains("xnum=")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String s : list) {
        String x = s.replace("xnum=","");
        finalList.add(x);
    }

    System.out.println(finalList);
```